# how to ignore whitespaces in fscanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I need to use `fscanf` to ignore all the white spaces and to not keep it.
I tried to use something like the combination between `(*)` and `[^\n]` as: `fscanf(file," %*[^\n]s",);`
Of course it crashed, is there any way to do it only with `fscanf`?

code:

```
int funct(char* name)
{
   FILE* file = OpenFileToRead(name);
   int count=0; 
   while(!feof(file)) 
   {
       fscanf(file," %[^\n]s");
       count++;
   }
   fclose(file);
   return count;
}
```

Solved !
change the original `fscanf()` to :
 `fscanf(file," %*[^\n]s")`;
 read all the line exactly as `fgets()` but didnt keep it!

Comment: Can we see the code that crashed? We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: <code>
int funct(char* name)
{

 FILE* file = OpenFileToRead(name);
 int count=0;
 while(!feof(file))
 {
  fscanf(file," %[^\n]s");
  count++;
 }
 fclose(file);
 return count;
}
</code>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a space (" ") in the fscanf format causes it to read and discard whitespace on the input until it finds a non-whitespace character, leaving that non-whitespace character on the input as the next character to be read. So you can do things like:

```
fscanf(file, " "); // skip whitespace
getc(file);        // get the non-whitespace character
fscanf(file, " "); // skip whitespace
getc(file);        // get the non-whitespace character
```

or

```
fscanf(file, " %c %c", &char1, &char2); // read 2 non-whitespace characters, skipping any whitespace before each
```

from:

[Ignoring whitepace with fscanf or fgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316313/ignoring-whitepace-with-fscanf-or-fgets)

Answer (score 3):

from the fscanf man page:

```
   A directive is one of the following:
  ·      A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.;
          see isspace(3)).  This directive matches  any  amount  of  white
          space, including none, in the input.
```

so

```
fscanf(file, " %s\n");
```

will skip all whitespace before reading in characters.

Comment: `fscanf(file, " %s\n")` has problems: 1) No destination to match `%s`. 2) `" "` in front of `"%s"` is not needed as `"%s"` will consume leading whitespace anyways. 3) `"\n"` does the same unneeded scanning of whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is crashing because you have a `%s` in your format specifier in the `fscanf` call, and you don't pass `fscanf` a `char *` to which you want it to write the string it finds.

See http://www.cs.utah.edu/~zachary/isp/tutorials/io/io.html.