# Ignore leading white space when reading a line from a text file in C

Tags: c

I have a text file with the following contents.

```
I am David. I live in San Diego at \u US \a zip code 95559
                      Mary has a little lamb in my yard \n
```

I am trying to read them line by line and use `strtok()` to extract sub-string. The extraction is working fine, but I want to skip the leading white space when reading line by line from the file. I want to skip only the leading white space but retain the other white spaces encountered after a valid character.

I tried adjusting the pointer to start at the index where `isspace()` is invalid. It still doesn't work for me.

Sample code attached below.

```
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE 255 

void ExtractData(FILE *fp)
{
   for (char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE]; fgets(buf, (int)sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL;)
   {
       char *cp;

       for (cp = buf; isspace(*cp); cp++)
           ;

       for (; (cp = strtok(cp, "ABC")); cp = NULL)
           puts(cp);
   }
}
```

Comment: `cp = NULL` should presumably be `cp != NULL`

Comment: @NeilButterworth: No; the assignment is useful (it means the next iteration continues scanning the same string); the comparison would not be useful (a no-op).

Comment: If you only want to skip leading white space, don't use the `strtok()` loop.  The `isspace()` loop skips the leading white space.  A `puts(cp)` would double-space the input without no leading spaces on the second line.  (Though since there are none of the letters `A`, `B`, or `C` in the input, it won't make much difference this time.)  Your example data isn't 100% clear. The `\u` sequence is meant to be a backslash and a `u`?  But is the `\a` sequence meant to be a backslash and an `a` and  the `\n` sequence meant to be a backslash and an `n`?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly? Your code [Works for me](http://ideone.com/dB6rdL).

Comment: Submitted the assignment as part of class work and i get this error from their auto verification tool. It's probably trying it with a different file.  Let me update the main post with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `fscanf(file, " ")`

This has been addressed over here, too: [how to ignore whitespaces in fscanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712572/how-to-ignore-whitespaces-in-fscanf)