# Scanning double number in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I would like to scan a matrix from a text file but it seems like the code I wrote works only for integer but not float.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp;
  int i, j;
  char s[MAX], ch;

  if ((fp = fopen("3.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("can not open this file!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  int row = 0;
  while (fgets(s, MAX, fp) != NULL) //Count the line
    row++;

  rewind(fp); //

  int col = 0; //Count the col
  while (ch != '\n') //(ch=fgetc(fp))!='\n'&&(ch=fgetc(fp))!='\r'
  {
    if (ch == ' ') col++;
    ch = fgetc(fp);
  }
  col++; //

  double** jz = malloc(row * sizeof(double*)); //Allocate spaces
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    jz[i] = malloc(col * sizeof(double));

  rewind(fp);

  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) //Read in the data
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      if (!fscanf(fp, "%lf", &jz[i][j])) {
        break;
      }
    }

  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) //Print the matrix
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      printf("%lf\t", jz[i][j]);
      if (j + 1 == col) printf("\n");
    }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

For example, a 1*3 matrix **`56.154 59.365 98.3333`** will appear to be all **`0.0000`**

I would like to know where I did wrong.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Works fine for me http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVUVSNlZ3VUQxN0U

Comment: May be a whitespace issue.  Try `fscanf(fp, "%lf ", ...)` (space after `%lf`) per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13316942/2877364).  **Also,** your `fscanf` test should be `if(fscanf(...)!=1)` since you are expecting to match one item.

Comment: `while(ch!='\n')` is an infinite loop should the file contain text with no `'\n'`.

Comment: Older compilers do not understand `l` in `printf()`.  Use `printf("%f\t",jz[i][j]);`.  Use `printf("%e\t",jz[i][j]);` for better debugging.

Comment: "0.0000" is certainly not OP's _true_ output.  Posting the _exact_ text is more useful than describing the output.

Comment: @cxw appending a space as in `fscanf(fp, "%lf ", ...)`  does not change the `fscanf()` results regardless of input.  The only thing it does it advance the file pointer to the next non-white-space.  OTOH `if(fscanf(...)!=1)` is a _very_ good idea.  Later code needs to print taking into consideration of an early `fscanf()` failure.

Comment: There is no matrx (aka 2D array) in your code, nothing which can be used as one or point to one.

Comment: I note  Wallkan's link (which is awesome :) ) is a Linux x86_64 instance with 8-byte `double`s.  What system are you running on?  Do `uname -a` if it's a Unix-like (including Mac OS X) machine.  Also, what compiler and version are you using?  You could also try scanning a single `double` value into a typecast `char` array and see exactly which bytes come out to see if you have size or endianness issues.  Try, for example, `-7.84796060836e-315` (thanks to [this](https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/)).

Comment: @chux updated screen shot. Thanks